# TypeError: float() argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-analysis

I'm new with python, I have a problem with array in python. So I have a data with a list like this and I give a variable name of this list is fitur:

```
[['F11', '1', '0', '0'], ['F2', '1', '1', '0'], ['F4', '1', '0', '0']]
```

And then I have a probability with condition positif and negatif, in index[0] is belongs to `F11` index[1] belongs to `F2` and index[2] belongs to `F4`

```
Here is positif (bpf_pos)
[0.42857142857142855, 0.5714285714285714, 0.5714285714285714]
and here is negatif (bpf_neg)
[0.14285714285714285, 0.2857142857142857, 0.2857142857142857]
```

And I have the formula:

```
f_pd_neg = (bpf_neg[i] ** float(uji[1])) * ((1 - bpf_neg[i]) ** (1 - float(uji[1])))
f_pd_pos = (bpf_pos[i] ** float(uji[1])) * ((1 - bpf_pos[i]) ** (1 - float(uji[1])))
```

So here is my problem i wanna calculate probability in the formula with the fitur. For the example 
`bpf_neg[0] ** 1 (from the list in F11) * ((1- bpf_neg[0] ** (1 - 1)` and so on until the value in list F11 finished

And my expectation I have the output like this

```
Positif is:
0 [0.571428571,0.571428571,0.428571429]
1 [0.428571429,0.571428571,0.571428571]
2 [0.571428571,0.428571429,0.428571429]
Negatif is:
0 [0.285714286,0.285714286,0.714285714]
1 [0.142857143,0.857142857,0.857142857]
2 [0.285714286,0.714285714,0.714285714]
```

And this is my code:

```
d_neg = []
d_pos = []
for i, uji in enumerate(ab):
    f_pd_neg = (bpf_neg[i] ** float(uji[1])) * ((1 - bpf_neg[i]) ** (1 - float(uji[1])))
    f_pd_pos = (bpf_pos[i] ** float(uji[1])) * ((1 - bpf_pos[i]) ** (1 - float(uji[1])))
    d_pos.append(f_pd_pos)
    d_neg.append(f_pd_neg)
```

I tried `float(uji[1:])` I got the error `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

How can I fix it? and I hope you understand because my english was terrible

Comment: what is in `ab` variable, can you give some example

Comment: In `float(uji[1:])` You are feeding a list-slice to `float(...)` - it can only accept a number or a string. Not a slice of a list. use `print(type(uji))` to view what type it is. [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - maybe your intent gets clearer if you provide a real  [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is variable `[['F11', '1', '0', '0'], ['F2', '1', '1', '0'], ['F4', '1', '0', '0']]` @zimdero

Comment: the type of `uji` is  `<type 'list'>` , So how can I fix that @PatrickArtner

Comment: `uji` is of type `list` that mean that you can slice it by `uji[1:]` it will give you `['1','0','0']` but you can't transform `list` to type `float`, how you want to use `uji[1:]` give me example and i will show you the result

Comment: So if the bpf_pos is `index [0]` you must calculate it with fitur in the `index[0]`

for the example is bpf_pos `indx[0] = 0.4285....` and the fitur[0] is `['F11', '1', '0', '0']`

so the formula for index[0]:
`f_pd_pos = (0.4285^1) x (1-0.4285)^(1-1) = .....
                = (0.4285^0) x (1-0.4285)^(0-0) = .....
                = (0.4285^0) x (1-0.4285)^(0-0) = ......`

for index[1]:
`f_pd_pos = (0.5714^1) x (1-0.5714)^(1-1) = .....
                = (0.5714^1) x (1-0.5714)^(0-1) = .....
                = (0.5714^0) x (1-0.5714)^(0-0) = .....`
@zimdero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RazBarb try this, i think i understand and result is the same,

```
lst = [['F11', '1', '0', '0'], ['F2', '1', '1', '0'], ['F4', '1', '0', '0']]

bpf_pos = [0.42857142857142855, 0.5714285714285714, 0.5714285714285714]
bpf_neg = [0.14285714285714285, 0.2857142857142857, 0.2857142857142857]

d_neg = []
d_pos = []
for i, uji in enumerate(lst):
    f_pd_neg = []
    f_pd_pos = []
    for x in uji[1:]:
        f_pd_neg.append(round((bpf_neg[i] ** float(x)) * ((1 - bpf_neg[i]) ** (1 - float(x))), 9) * 10)
        f_pd_pos.append(round((bpf_pos[i] ** float(x)) * ((1 - bpf_pos[i]) ** (1 - float(x))), 9) * 10)
    d_neg.append(f_pd_neg)
    d_pos.append(f_pd_pos)

for i, neg in enumerate(d_neg):
    print(i, neg)

for i, pos in enumerate(d_pos):
    print(i, pos)
```

**Output**

```
# pos
0 [0.142857143, 0.857142857, 0.857142857]
1 [0.285714286, 0.285714286, 0.714285714]
2 [0.285714286, 0.714285714, 0.714285714]

# neg
0 [0.428571429, 0.571428571, 0.571428571]
1 [0.571428571, 0.571428571, 0.428571429]
2 [0.571428571, 0.428571429, 0.428571429]
```

**Output after multiply every column by 10**

```
[1.4285714299999999, 8.57142857, 8.57142857]
[2.8571428599999997, 2.8571428599999997, 7.142857139999999]
[2.8571428599999997, 7.142857139999999, 7.142857139999999]
[4.28571429, 5.71428571, 5.71428571]
[5.71428571, 5.71428571, 4.28571429]
[5.71428571, 4.28571429, 4.28571429]
```

Comment: Thats work, Thank you so much, I have one more question if you don't mind how can I multiply every column in that output? @zimdero

Comment: @RozBarb check this example i multiply every column by 10,